# Nobility manga where the female main character is forced to cross-dress by her family but encounters demigods

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

The website I used to read that manga on is sadly shut down, but there was this specific nobility manga where the female main character (FMC) was hated by her "family" that were like her cousins or something, and essentially forced her via potions / magic to look like a boy.

The FMC then gets really depressed and essentially is okay with dying, but the demigods reach out to her for some reason? I don't remember the plot because that manga itself was all over the place, but I do remember that there were around five demigods (male and female) and, essentially, she moves out of that place and starts to work as a magic investigator.

In the last chapter that I still remember, she goes in disguise to a school because she had to find out something about a specific noble girl.

I forgot to add that the FMC is then okay with her androgynous look and, up to where I read it, didn't change her appearance or plan to do so. The manga was in full color and the FMC's hair was long and light brown, similar to that of the FMC from *Beware of the Villainess!*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: it was in full color! and the hair color was brown, a light brown similar to the fmc from ''beware of the villainess''

Comment: You mention the FL has long hair - is that at all times, including when she's dressed/magicked up as a male?

Comment: @qazmlpok yes, she never cuts it, generally her appearance doesnt change, and they never explained how she stayed ''androgynus'' because physically continues to have a built of a man

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***[Aria of the Withered Branch](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/aria-of-the-withered-branch)***.

> Alcheris Voygianna has had enough. Enraged, purposeless, and no longer wanting to go on after years of torment, she runs away with her stepmother's ring. But when she crushes the ring and falls asleep after failing to end her own life, she dreams of five demigods, who greet her in person a week later after she awakes! Their one request to her is this: live on so that they may live forever. In return, they promise to make her life worth living, but can they uphold that promise?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "Aria of the Withered Branch."]

When Alcheris' mother died, her father brought his mistress and illegitimate daughter home to live with them, and forced Alcheris to live as a boy to ensure that his other daughter would succeed him as head of the household, as the family tradition dictated that the next head must be female.

The father continued to favour his other daughter in subsequent years, largely ignoring Alcheris until she reached adulthood, at which point he gave her a recommendation letter for a civil service job in an embassy, and made it clear that she was no longer welcome in the family home.

Shortly before Alcheris left, her stepmother snatched the necklace she'd inherited from her mother and tossed it into the fireplace. Alcheris subsequently retrieved her charred necklace and stole her stepmother's ring on her way out of the house, then booked a room in an inn.

Upon entering her room, Alcheris vented her anger at the cruel treatment she'd received from her father and stepmother by hurling her stepmother's ring to the floor and stamping on it, breaking the jewel inside it. Tired of living, she drank a vial of poison, and laid down on the bed to die.

Rather than dying though, she had a dream about five people she'd never seen before; a little girl, a young woman, two young men, and an older man. When she awoke, she was informed that a week had passed, and that she had visitors, those being the five people she'd dreamed about.

They explained that they were 'Binah,' god-like beings with one setback; their immortal lifespans are bound to a 'token.' When Alcheris broke her stepmother's ring, she became their token, and as such, they need her to live forever in order to do so themselves, otherwise they'll only live to the age of 300.

As their lives depend on hers, these beings become a support system for Alcheris, and with their encouragement, she regains the will to live and takes the job her father arranged for her at the embassy. Soon after, she's asked to help investigate a haunted house tourist attraction where two women went missing.

Regarding Alcheris' hair length and gender identity, as a child, her light brown hair was cut short and her family made her drink a potion to prevent the bodily changes associated with puberty. As an adult, she has long hair, tied in a braided ponytail, but continues to present as male while secretly regarding herself as female.

You can read the full manhwa at [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/aria-of-the-withered-branch/info).

Comment: yes!!!!!!! omg thank you so much!!!!!! how did you find this cause i could not find it for the life of me!!!!

Comment: I searched for it on Baka-Updates with the `Abusive Family Member/s` and `Female Disguised as Male` tags, and filtered the search to show only manhwa.